# How to Remove Specific div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, element

can someone please tell me how to remove div element using javascript.
I'm on a Shopify theme edit.

I need to this to be  or

Comment: post your code. Whatever you have done

Comment: How are you targeting the div to be removed ? what identifier are you going to use ?

Answer (score 0):

First, get the div that you need to remove.

and then remove the div from its parent.

```
var element = document.getElementById("childDiv");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example hope this will help you!

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('did').remove();
    this.remove();
};
```

```html
<div id='did'>
<p id='pid'>Hello World</p>
<input id='btn' type="submit" value='REMOVE THAT!!!'/>
</div>
```